# Java to C# conversion: invalid error on the `:`

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game in Unity using C#. I found a tutorial that is helping me create my project, however it is in Java. I came across this line of code and I'm not sure how to convert it to C#:

```
var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
```

I'm getting an invalid error on the `:`

Comment: Looks more like Scala than Java.

Comment: Are you sure this is java?

Comment: That sign is used for extending or implementing other classes or interfaces in C#, so it must be a class not var in C#, in Java it is not valid. I don't think this is any of either languages.

Comment: It's Javascript. Unity supports C#, Javascript and Boo.

Comment: This is Javascrit, not Java.

Comment: I'm not a Javascript developer but I've never seen a variable defined with `:`. Is this an alternative notation?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's an optional type specifier

Comment: @ChrisMantle: I can't seem to find any information related to it, could you point me to a resource that talks about it?

Comment: Can you please post a link to that tutorial?

Comment: Sorry guys - my bad! It is Javascript! I re-listened to it and it's Javascript. That's embarrassing! Sorry about that! I appreciate your help! 

Here's the video I'm watching: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wxe1IUu5QA

Comment: @JeroenVannevel There's some reference to it in this [wiki page](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=JavaScript_Type_Inference), under the _(i) Ok. So where I do have to declare types then?_ section. The Unity implementation of JavaScript ("UnityScript") has some differences to vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisMantle: thanks for pointing me to it! You learn a little every day.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenVannevel for the encouragement. You are so right and I still have A LOT to learn! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
```

or

```
CharacterController controller = (CharacterController)GetComponent(typeof(CharacterController));
```

or

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent(typeof(CharacterController)) as CharacterController;
```

or

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent("CharacterController") as CharacterController;
```

This is **Javascript**, not **Java**. Read this (it misses a ; though): http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Comment: Did you not read the documentation yourself or why are you showing 4 different?

Comment: When I answered the question, I did not know which tutorial was he/she referring to, so I thought of writing all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

That would be JavaScript, and the corresponding C# should be:

```
var controller = (CharacterController) GetComponent(typeof(CharacterController));
```

EDIT: Edited for correctness. [Debojyoti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585857/718972) has the better, generic alternative.

Comment: oh sorry, I thought it was Java because the guy on the video said "let me write some Java" here. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In C# that would be:

```
CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
```